# Apply series of transformations to pandas DataFrame object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am relatively new to Python programming. I have a pandas DataFrame object say obj1. I need to apply a series of transformation to records stored in obj1['key']. Suppose obj1['key'] has 300 entries and I need to apply func1 then func2 then func3 on each of the 300 entries and store the final result in obj1['key']. 
One way would be to do as below. Is there a better way to do the same?

```
obj1['key']=[func3(func2(func1(item))) for item in obj1['key']]
```

Python generators can't be used for this purpose right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use the default method [DataFrame.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

```
df = df.apply(f1).apply(f2).apply(fn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

define a function

```
def recursivator(x, fs):
    return recursivator(fs[-1](x), fs[:-1]) if len(fs) > 0 else x
```

`x` is the thing being operated on, `fs` is a list of functions.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: recursivator(x, fs))
```